# Unable to download blob loaded into an iframe

Tags: javascript, typescript, iframe

Following is my code which sets src attribute of an iframe to the blob url that I have created:-

```
function downloadFromIframeUsingBody(filebody: any) {
  const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
  const newurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([filebody.data],{type: 'application/pdf'}));
  iframe.setAttribute('src', newurl);
  const register = () => {
    if (iframe.contentWindow) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Clean after 1 minute, by then it should already have started downloading
        iframe.parentNode!.removeChild(iframe);
      }, 60000);
    }  else {
      setTimeout(register, 100);
    }
  };
  register();
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

What I would like is for this iframe to download the blob containing pdf to be downloaded automatically. Currently nothing happens when this gets executed.

Comment: @Kaiido yes using anchor tag I can download, but I was wondering if I can do the same iframe or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "download" as "save on disk" then just use an HTMLAnchorElement and its `download` attribute.

Or even handle all the edge cases (old IE and Safari quirks) with the ligthweight [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) script.

```js
var blob = new Blob(["I'm just a text file..."], {type: 'plain/text'});

saveAs(blob, 'myFile.txt');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

Note that this is true for any cases. iframe hack is just a bad hack that should only be used when it's been determined that no other better ways will work.

Now to explain why it won't work, well, it's because browsers actually are able to display pdf files, and will thus [try to] do it instead of forcing a download.

```html
<iframe src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mozilla/pdf.js/test/pdfs/S2.pdf"></iframe>
```

(Note that current Chrome seems to have a bug that will make the pdf-reader to fail when in nested iframes, so [here is a link to a plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/mZpoIdQmuafksDZE?preview), where you can see it live in this browser by clicking the expand button on the right panel.